# GIMP plugin crash

Tags: crash, plugins, gimp

I'm trying to create a parchment-like image following [this tutorial](https://www.gimpusers.com/tutorials/old-pergament-paper). Everything goes well until I reach step 8. I open `Filters > Light and Shadow > Lightning effects...` and set it up as required in the guide. Then, when I enable the `Bump Map` option and select the "crinkle-Channel" the plug-in crashes and I get the following error:

> Plug-in crashed: "lighting.exe" (C:\Program Files\GIMP
>   2\lib\gimp\2.0\plug-ins\lighting\lighting.exe)
>
> The dying plug-in may have messed up GIMP's internal state. You may
>   want to save your images and restart GIMP to be on the safe side.

([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwq5Y.png))

I have done some tries before creating my final image and everything went well, then the plug-in suddenly began to crash.

GIMP only tells me that the plug-in crashed, so I don't have a clue about what to look for. I tried to:

1. clean the system
2. reboot the PC
3. run GIMP as administrator

but nothing changed.

How can I understand what's the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Could be a bug. Which Gimp version? 32 or 64 bit? Windows version? 32 or 64 bit? Note that you tutorial is 12 years old, and things have changed quite a bit in 12 years.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem but there is a bug in the bumpmap plugin in 2.10.14 which is not in 2.10.12, so if you are on 2.10.14, try to downgrade.

Comment: @xenoid GIMP 2.10.14 for Windows x64. Downgraded to 2.10.12, now it works. Thanks a lot!